# How to add stroke to part of text that overlaps other text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, outline

Using Adobe Illustrator, how would I achieve the stroke around the words "happy birthday" where they overlap the word "Jesus" in the image below?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147721/convert-black-outline-above-white-shapes-to-transparent-in-illustrator/147724#147724

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Black Outline Above White Shapes to Transparent in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147721/convert-black-outline-above-white-shapes-to-transparent-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 0):

If the text is on a white background you can just add white stroke to the whole upper line of text.

Make sure that the upper line of text is a separate object placed above the other text.

Add a stroke in the *Appearance* panel. Drag down the stroke so it's below *Characters* to add the stroke to the whole text instead of to the individual letters.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think to use the Appearance panel to add the stroke. It wasn't showing correctly when I just did it from the swatch window. THanks again.